# React material-ui AvatarGroup rounded shape for extra child

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I control the shape of the extra item that is appended to a React Material-UI AvatarGroup (when the number of Avatars is more than `max`) so that it matches the `rounded` variant of the Avatars.

[image]

```
      <AvatarGroup max={4}>
            <Avatar
              variant="rounded"
              alt="Remy Sharp"
              src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
            />
            <Avatar
              variant="rounded"
              alt="Travis Howard"
              src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg"
            />
            <Avatar
              variant="rounded"
              alt="Cindy Baker"
              src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg"
            />
            <Avatar
              variant="rounded"
              alt="Agnes Walker"
              src="/static/images/avatar/4.jpg"
            />
            <Avatar
              variant="rounded"
              alt="Trevor Henderson"
              src="/static/images/avatar/5.jpg"
            />
          </AvatarGroup>
```

API doc doesn't mention how to set this: https://material-ui.com/api/avatar-group/

Although the "next" version does: https://next.material-ui.com/es/api/avatar-group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the shape's style using a mui global class selectors:

```
import React from "react";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import AvatarGroup from "@material-ui/lab/AvatarGroup";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "& .MuiAvatar-root": { borderRadius: 0 }
    }
  })
);

export default function GroupAvatars() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <AvatarGroup max={4} className={classes.root}>
      <Avatar
        alt="Remy Sharp"
        variant="rounded"
        src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
      />
      <Avatar
        alt="Travis Howard"
        variant="rounded"
        src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg"
      />
      <Avatar
        alt="Cindy Baker"
        variant="rounded"
        src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg"
      />
      <Avatar
        alt="Agnes Walker"
        variant="rounded"
        src="/static/images/avatar/4.jpg"
      />
      <Avatar
        alt="Trevor Henderson"
        variant="rounded"
        src="/static/images/avatar/5.jpg"
      />
    </AvatarGroup>
  );
}
```

please find a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-voqn5?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: Thanks! (And just set e.g. `borderRadius: 3` for rounded corners)